# How to use Aggregator correctly in apache camel to insert huge data into mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-camel

I am using apache camel to read huge XMLTYPE data from oracle DB (about 500M rows), process it and insert it into mongodb. I am using splitter for processing and the output message is in **org.bson.Document**.
The problem is with the aggregator, it returns either an exception  **Cannot deserialize as out of START_ARRAY token** or the number of inserted rows is very few (just 9 rows).

This the aggregator's code:

```java
public class dAggregator implements AggregationStrategy {
    @Override
    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
        Document newBody = newExchange.getIn().getBody(Document.class);
        ArrayList<Document> list = new ArrayList<>();
        if (oldExchange == null) {
            list.add(newBody);
            newExchange.getIn().setBody(list);
            return newExchange;
        } else {
            list.add(oldExchange.getIn().getBody(Document.class));
            return oldExchange;
        }
    }
}
```

Camel Context:

```xml
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    
    <threadPool id="myPool" rejectedPolicy="CallerRuns" threadName="spl" maxQueueSize="120" maxPoolSize="250" poolSize="80"/>
    <threadPool id="aggPool" rejectedPolicy="CallerRuns" threadName="agg" maxQueueSize="120" maxPoolSize="150" poolSize="50"/>
     
    <route streamCache="true">
        <from uri="timer://foo?repeatCount=1"/>
            <setBody>
                <constant>SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER</constant>
            </setBody>
            <to id="sql" uri="jdbc:myds?outputType=StreamList&resetAutoCommit=false&statement.fetchSize=100000"/>
            <split parallelProcessing="true" executorServiceRef="myPool" stopOnException="true" streaming="true">
                <simple>${in.body}</simple>
                <process ref="rowProcessor"/>
                <to uri="seda:toinsert?size=1000000&amp;blockWhenFull=true"/>
            </split>
    </route>

    <route streamCache="true">
        <from uri="seda:toinsert"/>
            <aggregate completionSize="50000" completionTimeout="30000" id="aggregate_1" strategyRef="aggStrategy" parallelProcessing="true" executorServiceRef="aggPool">
            <correlationExpression>
                <constant>true</constant>
            </correlationExpression>
            <to uri="mongodb:mongoBean?database=mydb&collection=customer&operation=insert"/>
    </route>

</camelContext>
```

Is there anything wrong or missing? Any thoughts or tips are more than welcome.

Comment: If `oldExchange` is not null, then your aggregator executes `list.add(oldExchange.getIn().getBody(Document.class));`, but the `list` created by `ArrayList<Document> list = new ArrayList<>();` is discarded.

Comment: Thank you i figured the problem out, instead of `oldExchange.getIn().getBody(Document.class)` the correct statement is `oldExchange.getIn().getBody(ArrayList.class)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Chin Huang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57719/chin-huang)'s advice, i changed `oldExchange.getIn().getBody(Document.class)` to `oldExchange.getIn().getBody(ArrayList.class)` and now it works perfectly.